# How to automatically launch python file once GUI has loaded on Raspbian Pixel

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I now this has been asked before, but I have spent hours and hours trying to find out how to do this and absolutely nothing has worked. I have a python file that I want to automatically run in a terminal window after the pi has booted and loaded its GUI.

I don't know what else to do, and the annoying thing is I had it working for the same project (it took a long time to find out how then as well), but the pi crashed today and I can't remember how to do it again. All I can remember is that I added something to a file ending in /autostart, if that helps.

Comment: Are you attempting to start this module after getting into the desktop top layer (Raspian, Mate, etc.) or did you want it to run in a X11 session in lieu of having the user get to the desktop. If so look at .Xsession and .xintric

Comment: @ShawnGordon I'm trying to get it to run once the GUI (raspbian) has loaded, just in a terminal window that automatically opens

Comment: Have you checked out this So question?http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4123/running-a-python-script-at-startup   or this tutorial https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/auto-run-python-programs-on-the-raspberry-pi/ ?

Comment: @ShawnGordon Just to let you know I managed to get it working, see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to launch a python file on startup by running `sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and adding `@lxterminal -e python /home/pi/weatherStation/core.py` at the end of the file

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues remembering where and how to do this.  Then it all seemed to change again with Buster.

Having just freshly installed Buster onto a new SD card, I had to go through the whole process again.  It's definitely easier the third or fourth time ;-)

I found that there was no **lxsession** folder in the path I had used before:

```
/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

**/home/pi/.config/lxsession** did not exist in the Buster I just installed (May 2020)

I found a 2020 Buster related article here:
   http://wideberry.com/autostart-python-script-after-boot-in-raspbian-buster/
and from that found the autostart file in this path:

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi
```

Note: this is a root file and will affect all users.

As I had previously found an issue with timings of when to issue the python command, I call a script to pause before running my python scripts.

I added an `@lxterminal` command in my `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` as follows:

```
lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@lxterminal -e /home/pi/StartCollectors.sh
@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

Note: as `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` this is a root protected file, it had to be edited with root powers, e.g. `sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

`StartCollectors.sh` contains this

```
#!/bin/bash
# started from the /etc/xdg/LXDE-pi/autostart file (reminder)
cd /home/pi/ETA2-copy
echo "starting House Collectors in 20 seconds"
sleep 10
echo "starting House Collectors in 10 seconds"
sleep 10 
lxterminal --working-directory='/home/pi/ETA2-copy' --command='python3 Hiverun.py' -t 'Hive'
lxterminal --working-directory='/home/pi/ETA2-copy' --command='python3 ETALog.py' -t 'ETA'
lxterminal --working-directory='/home/pi/ETA2-copy' --command='python3 ETADailySum.py' -t 'Summary'
echo "My work is done.  Closing in 10 seconds
sleep 10
exit
```

the -t options put a recognizable name on the terminal window.

It works.

BTW I collect data from an ETA PU15 boiler over my local Lan.  I collect data from my British Gas Hive home control system and the UK Met Office and integrate it into an sqlite table so that I can track the house performance.  Why?  Why not?  Call it a hobby.

I think this is my first answer on this forum.  I hope it conforms and that it helps others.