# How to start a python script after booting in Raspbian?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I made an app in Thonny that when I run it, shows a camera connected to RPI and shows the image in an interface. You can also use the keyboard to do some things in the interface, take photos, etc.

I always execute it using thonny (run button), but now, I am trying to autostart the program in python when Raspbian ends its starting (after a shutdown or reboot).

I tried to do it in 3 ways:

- autostart
- lxde-pi/autostart
- crontab

But it doesn't work. It starts Raspbian, but nothing more. Any ideas or code to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you could start it in `~/.bash_profile` it will then start at login

Comment: `autostart` definitely works. I would double check your code.

Comment: A common place to toss startup programs is `/etc/rc.local` (don't forget to add the `&` at the end so it doesn't keep the rest of the boot process from happening. You can also make an `init.d` version too, but you'll probably want to add your [runtime dependencies](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) in the script.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late for @mash_10, but for anyone else who lands here my solution that auto fires a bash script on the home folder.  To add new automatic startups I just add code to my personal bash script. This works on Buster rpi.

Details are in my answer here [How to automatically launch python file once GUI has loaded on Raspbian Pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913956/how-to-automatically-launch-python-file-once-gui-has-loaded-on-raspbian-pixel/61730679#61730679)